# How to pass variable asyncronously through different scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to do it.

I have two separate scripts. The first one generates an **interval** (or a timeout) to run a specified function every x seconds, i.e. reload the page.

The other script contains actions for a button to control (pause/play) this interval.

The pitfall here is that both sides must be **asyncronous** (both run when the document is loaded).

How could I properly use the interval within the second script?

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hm2d6d6L/4/

And here's the code for a quick view:

```
var interval;
// main script
(function($){
    $(function(){
        var reload = function() {
            console.log('reloading...');
        };
        // Create interval here to run reload() every time
    });
})(jQuery);

// Another script, available for specific users
(function($){
    $(function(){
        var $playerButton = $('body').find('button.player'),
            $icon         = $playerButton.children('i');
            buttonAction = function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).hasClass('playing')) {
                    // Pause/clear interval here
                    $(this).removeClass('playing').addClass('paused');
                    $icon.removeClass('glyphicon-pause').addClass('glyphicon-play');
                }
                else {
                    // Play/recreate interval here
                    $(this).removeClass('paused').addClass('playing');
                    $icon.removeClass('glyphicon-play').addClass('glyphicon-pause');
                }
            },
            buttonInit = function() {
                $playerButton.on('click', buttonAction);
            };
        buttonInit();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "use the interval", but you can make anything a global variable by attaching it to the `window` object. So you can do, for example, `window.reload=function(){}` and `window.interval=setInterval()`

Comment: that's right, but I was trying to find a way to pollute the global scope as little as possible.

Comment: The only way to get something "everywhere", as far as I know, in a any application, is to have it accessible from some global scope. That scope can either be the  javascript global scope (`window`), or maybe some other fancy scope, like the DOM, which is global as well, using `jQuery.data`.

Comment: I was trying to find out a way, I'm sure there are, to create a function with a closure enclosing reload, so that I can use it in the second script, from which I then could recreate/replay the interval which in turn would call reload(). Having that reload must be within the function passed to the jQuery object in the first script (run on DOM loaded). Not sure if I'm being clear.

Comment: @JonathanLerner Yes you can. "Global" is something of a relative term - you can have scopes within scopes within scopes. In javascript, only a function definition creates an inner scope (but in other languages any kind of block will do it). So if you do this: `(function() { var interval; // main script ... })();`both the functions inside the outer function will share the `interval` variable, but nothing else will have access to it.

Comment: @David Knipe it's my understanding that he needs actual global, not relative global... Not sure how your comment is relevant to this.

Comment: @JonathanLerner Why would he need an actual global? In fact, why would anyone ever need an actual global, apart from pre-defined things like `Object`, `setInterval`, etc?

Comment: @DavidKnipe If he wants to be able to stop the interval at any time, from anywhere, he needs to maintain a global handle on the IntervalID.

Comment: I hadn't realised it was two separate scripts. So yes, something will probably have to go in the global namespace. Unless he's using requirejs or something, which he doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a simple event bus. This is pretty easy to create with jQuery, since you already have it in there:

```
// somewhere globally accessible (script 1 works fine)
var bus = $({});

// script 1
setInterval(function() {
    reload();
    bus.trigger('reload');
}, 1000);

// script 2
bus.on('reload', function() {
    // there was a reload in script 1, yay!
});
```

Comment: So how could I access the interval from the second script to take control on it?

Comment: Can you define your usage of the term "internet" here?

Comment: I guess you mean "interval", or "timeout" might fit better in this case since it will reload the page. I simply need to play/stop this interval, which runs the reload function, both of them set in the first script, from the button control script (the second one).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I'm sure it's not the best one, but it works.

As you pointed out, I eventually needed at least one global variable to act as a join between both scripts, and the use of a closure to overcome asyncronous issues. Note that I manipulate the button within reload, just to remark that sometimes it's not as easy as moving code outside in the global namespace:

Check it out here in jsFiddle: [yay! this works!](http://jsfiddle.net/hm2d6d6L/13/)

And here's the code:

```
var intervalControl;
// main script
(function($){
    $(function(){
        var $playerButton = $('body').find('button.player'),
        reload = function() {
            console.log('reloading...');
            $playerButton.css('top', parseInt($playerButton.css('top')) + 1);
        };
        var interval = function(callback) {
            var timer,
                playing = false;
            this.play = function() {
                if (! playing) {
                    timer = setInterval(callback, 2000);
                    playing = true;
                }
            };
            this.pause = function() {
                if (playing) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    playing = false;
                }
            };
            this.play();
            return this;
        };
        intervalControl = function() {
            var timer = interval(reload); 
            return {
                play: function() {
                     timer.play();   
                },
                pause: function(){
                     timer.pause();   
                }
            }   
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

// Another script, available for specific users
(function($){
    $(function(){
        var $playerButton = $('body').find('button.player'),
            $icon         = $playerButton.children('i'),
            interval;
            buttonAction = function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).hasClass('playing')) {
                    interval.pause();
                    $(this).removeClass('playing').addClass('paused');
                    $icon.removeClass('glyphicon-pause').addClass('glyphicon-play');
                }
                else {
                    interval.play();
                    $(this).removeClass('paused').addClass('playing');
                    $icon.removeClass('glyphicon-play').addClass('glyphicon-pause');
                }
            },
            buttonInit = function() {
                $playerButton.on('click', buttonAction);
                interval = intervalControl();
            };
        buttonInit();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any better suggestion is most welcome.